# Создать переменную инстанса для получения значеня и невозвратной функции

Tags: swift, mobile-development

```
@IBAction func testField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    let testText = sender.text
}
```

Надо передать `sender.text` в другие функции, но функция `testField` не возвращает значений. Как быть?

Comment: что Вы имеете в виду? Что сама функция не возвращает? Так она и не должна. Или не можете взять testText? Тогда сделайте его переменной полем класса.

Comment: @VAndrJ он это и спрашивает. как это сделать переменной

Comment: а зачем было новый аккаунт создавать?

Comment: Ну я в функцию не могу передать testText! Я не могу вывести его из testField!

Comment: Мне говорят что надо подождать с вопросами(((

Comment: Для меня загадка честно говоря какого я вижу слово FUNC, но не могу ничего вернуть из нее!!! Зачем так делать?????????????!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Я честно не понял, в чем проблема? Ваша функция ничего не возвращает так как это `@IBAction`. Самый простой вариант, создайте глобальную переменную (в не зоне видимости функции) и далее в теле функции присвойте ей значение, вот и все.

Comment: Спасибо Vitali Eller! Разобрался!!! Помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте переменную не в зоне видимости функции. Далее в теле функции присвоить ей значение. И далее сможете использовать переменную в любой другой функции.

```
var testText: String?

@IBAction func testField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    testText = sender.text
} 

func printTestText() {
    print(testText!)
}
```